# How do you create dependent dropdown lists in excel using EPPLUS for C#?

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I'm tinkering with generating excel files with EPPLUS / C#. I can create a dropdown list, that's not a problem. What I'm struggling to find an example of is how to create dependent dropdown lists (e.g., country, region)

Anyone done this?

Here's an example of just adding a dropdown:

```
    var range = ExcelRange.GetAddress(1, 2, ExcelPackage.MaxRows, 2);
    var val = ws.DataValidations.AddListValidation(range);
    val.ShowErrorMessage = true;
    val.Formula.Values.Add("US");
    val.Formula.Values.Add("CA");
```

So what I'd like to do is have a region cell right next to the country, that of which is filtered based on the country selected.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this using OFFSET, MATCH, and COUNTA excel functions. I watched this video and was able to implement Leila's solution [Smart Dependent Dropdown lists in Excel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VxReJslyJm8). She walks through each excel function used. I followed along with my own sheet and I was able to implement into my code.

For example:

```
using (var package = new ExcelPackage("filename"))
{
 var foodsSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Foods");
 foodsSheet.Cells["A1"].Value = "Fruit";
 foodsSheet.Cells["A2"].Value = "Apple";
 foodsSheet.Cells["A3"].Value = "Orange";
 foodsSheet.Cells["A4"].Value = "Banana";

 foodsSheet.Cells["B1"].Value = "Veggies";
 foodsSheet.Cells["B2"].Value = "Lettuce";
 foodsSheet.Cells["B3"].Value = "Tomato";
 foodsSheet.Cells["B4"].Value = "Onion";

 var dataList = foodsSheet.DataValidations.AddListValidation("D1");
 dataList.Formula.ExcelFormula = "$A$1:$B$1";
 var dependentList = foodsSheet.DataValidations.AddListValidation("E1");

 //This is where the video comes in handy.
 dependentList.Formula.ExcelFormula = 
     "OFFSET($A$1,1, +
     MATCH($D$1,$A$1:$B$1,0)-1, +
     COUNTA(OFFSET($A$1,1, +
     MATCH($D$1,$A$1:$B$1,0)-1,5,1)),1)"
  package.Save()
 }
```

I hope this helps!